# Where should "imply" be placed in this formalisation?

Tags: formal-methods

I have to formalize the following sentence:

> If any house is green then there exists a horse that is white.

I have formalized it the following way:
$$\forall(x)(\mathit{house}(x)\rightarrow \mathit{green}(x))\rightarrow \exists(y)(\mathit{horse}(y) \rightarrow \mathit{white}(y))$$
A friend formalized it in a slightly different way:
$$\forall(x)((\mathit{house}(x)\rightarrow \mathit{green}(x))\rightarrow \exists(y)(\mathit{horse}(y) \rightarrow \mathit{white}(y)))$$
Notice how in my formalisation, the right-most implication is separated from the $\forall(x)$, while in his formalisation the $\forall(x)$ encompasses the last implies as well.

I believe my way is correct because I think the sentence means that all houses being green implies that there's a white horse, and not that for any green house there's a white horse.

We haven't been able to reach a conclusion by ourselves, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $\exists(x)(house(x)\wedge green(x))\implies \exists(y)(horse(y)\wedge white(y))$

Comment: You proposition is satisfied if there are two houses, one green and the other not green, and no white horses, while the statement in your problem should be false in that case. If there are two houses, one green and one note green, then $\forall(x)(house(x)\implies green(x))$ is false, since the not-green house is a counter example. Therefore, automatically the full formula is a proposition that is true. But then the statement in the problem is false, since there are no white horses even though there is one green house.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the "any" here means there's at least a green house and not that all of them are green? I'm quite confused by this to be honest since I don't speak english natively

Comment: Yes, in English, **any** is an ambiguous word and should be avoided in mathematics precisely because of this. It can mean either **at least one** or also **all**. For example, the use in "Any contribution will help" is mostly understood as "All contributions will help".  However, in "If any contribution is given I will double it" it means "If there exists a contribution, then I will double it". That is inconvenient because in mathematics the distinction between $\exists$ and $\forall$ is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to break your statement up:

> If (any house is green) then (there exists a horse that is white).

An equivalent statement would be

> If some house is green, then some horse is white.

The condition is "there exists a house which is green", and the consequence is "there exists a horse which is white".

If we wanted a different quantifier for the condition, we would change it to

> If all houses are green, then some horse is white.

As you mention in the comments, this is more of a question in the semantics of the English language. This doesn't necessarily make it a bad question, since it highlights the need for a logical formalism which transcends such linguistic difficulties.

You can formalize the original statement as
$$
(\exists x \, \mathit{house}(x) \land \mathit{green}(x)) \to
(\exists y \, \mathit{horse}(y) \land \mathit{white}(y)).
$$
The prenex form is
$$
\forall x \exists y \, (\mathit{house}(x) \land \mathit{green}(x)) \to (\mathit{horse}(y) \land \mathit{white}(y)),
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\forall x \exists y \, \lnot \mathit{house}(x) \lor \lnot \mathit{green}(x) \lor (\mathit{horse}(y) \land \mathit{white}(y)).
$$

Comment: I see your point. Assuming the quantifier were "all" instead of "any", which one of the formalisations I mentioned would you consider correct?

Comment: You can formulate the modified statement in several ways, using either $\exists$ or $\forall$.

Comment: Hmm, okay, your edit has actually clarified a couple of things. Thanks for your help, I'll mark your answer as accepted.